I want to setup two Hyperledger Networks on the same physical machine?
Using the hyperledger Docs, I was successful in setting up one network using the network.sh up etc etc commands.
But my project requies two seperate blockchains for different applications.
I want both of them on my PC to create a integrated website using both of them
I tried to change the port numbers in core.yaml file and orderer.yaml files.
It did not work ad the error was mychannel not found.
I also tried to change the network names for both the networks but that did not work.
When I try to just up both the networks at the same time the second network stops the first network's containers
